# Acceder al resultset en un consulta de jstl

Tags: sql, jsp, jstl

tengo hecha una query a traves de sql, en l aque le paso el valor de un id, y recibo unicamente el nombre del equipo al que referencia, pero estoy teniendo problemas para mostrarlo en l apagina jsp.

```
<sql:setDataSource var="db" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  
 url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/proyecto"  
 user="root"  password=""/>
<sql:query dataSource="${db}" var="equipoLocal">
    SELECT nombre FROM equipo WHERE idEquipo=${partidosTemp.idEquipoLocal}
</sql:query>
<td> ${equipoLocal}</td>
```

esa es la parte del codigo y estp es lo que me muestra en el jsp
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.
Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una búsqueda de org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql nos lleva [al Javadoc de la clase](http://javadox.com/org.glassfish.web/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/1.2.3/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/sql/ResultImpl.html) y al método *public java.lang.Object[][] getRowsByIndex()*.

Esto te devuelve todas las filas del resultado, con cada fila siendo un array de los campos retornados. Como solo devuelves un campo, y supongo que solo hay un registro, lo que tienes que hacer es

```
<td> ${equipoLocal.rowsByIndex[0][0]}</td>
```

Dicho esto, el diseño es curioso, hacer una consulta (de hecho dos) para cada fila es raro. Los más normal sería que hicieras una única consulta para toda la tabla (consultar partidos junto con joins para sacar los nombres de los equipos) e iteraras sobre ella. Lo que parece indicar tu código es MUY ineficiente y lento.